# How to trim trailing spaces before the column value in SQL plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to export the sql select query values to .txt format file through sql plus. In the generated output file trailing spaces are appearing before the first column values.

[Attached is the image which contains the data displayed in SQL plus and how it is displayed in the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si8WL.png)

Below is the query I have tried to use.

```
SET UNDERLINE OFF;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
set feedback off;
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR FROM emp;
```

Can anyone suggest how to remove the trailing spaces before the first column values in SQL plus.

Comment: Use trimming functions.

Comment: tried, but not succeeded. any specific format that you can suggest in trimming functions?

Comment: I used rtrim() and ltrim() quite a few times.

Comment: It seems that you aren't happy with leading spaces, trailing spaces, spaces in between ... perhaps you should explain which result you **would** be satisfied with, preferably by posting expected sample result.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert numbers to char: to_char(empno) as empno

Comment: Trailing space before first column is removed but it generated lot of space between first and second column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format option as follows:

```
Column empno format 99999 -- number of 9's equal to max length 
Column ename format a15 -- replace 15 with max size of ename
```

Do same for other columns.

`99999` is used for number columns and `a<size>` is used for the string.